# How to get CSS div to fit contents

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

This is my first post, I have a problem shown below: since I am offsetting the 3 images by -172px to the right and have the position set as absolute I get these scroll bars when the content doesn't fit. I set the "home" section with h-screen but it only works if everything that needs to be show fits in the screen.

I want to remove the h-screen and just have the "home" section automatically fit everything.

How do I do that?

```css
.hero-img {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.img-container {
    max-width:345px;
    max-height:580px;
}

.inner{
    position: absolute;
    right: -172px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="home" class="main lg:pl-28 flex flex-wrap flex-row w-full h-screen">
            <div class="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-5/12 justify-center lg:pr-28 bg-green-200">
                <p class="text-lg mb-0 text-gray-600">Title 1</p>
                <h1 class="mb-4 text-3xl md:text-5xl font-bold leading-tight text-center md:text-left slide-in-bottom-h1">Title 2</h1>
                <p class="leading-normal text-base md:text-2xl mb-8 text-center md:text-left slide-in-bottom-subtitle">Title 3</p>
            </div>
            
            <!--Right Col-->
            <div class="outer w-full lg:w-7/12 overflow-x-hidden relative flex items-center bg-red-200">
                <div class="flex gap-4 inner">
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="hero-img">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="hero-img">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="hero-img">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Don't use position absolute. At first it will look like an easy fix to your layout problems but it only creates more problem along the way (like this one). Use flexbox or grid to create your layouts.

Comment: Can you show me how to do the above with flexbox layouts?

Comment: In desktop view or mobile view ?

Comment: Try it yourself, I am sure you can do it. :) Also I don't have any idea how the layout should really look and behave.

Comment: @cloned - the only thing I am confused about how how to use flexbox to position content partially off screen.

Comment: @Viira - desktop please, just point me in the right direction please!

Comment: I'm not sure about what is your desired output, can you show us in picture?

Comment: @Viira - run the code snippet and then click "full page" - I want it to look just like that, but when the screen isn't full screen I want the div to adapt to it's content and not have scroll bars.

Comment: I have ran your code It doesn't have scroll bar now!. scrollbar in the sense is it vertical or horizontal?

Comment: @viira the scrollbar come's into play with the screen is < 580px. Hence why h-screen is not appropriate

Comment: you can set `position:relative` for `.inner` on responsive view

Comment: @Viira - oh wow that does help a lot! but it resizes the images for some reason, do you have a solution to that? Also I am curious how to do this with flexbox, can you give me an example?

Comment: do you want both the home section and image section to be the same height ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237544/discussion-between-jac-and-viira).